# Appending "you save" below and adding the two costs in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, addition

```
<tr><td class="summaryitem"><a href="javascript:OpenRebatesWindow('/shop/Phones/PhonePricingRebates.aspx?action=devicepromo&amp;device=60c0ca0d-b68d-4edd-b667-0d4320b60ede');">Instant discount</a></td><td class="summaryprice">-$200.00</td></tr>


<tr class="last"><td class="summaryitem"><a href="javascript:OpenRebatesWindow('/shop/Phones/PhonePricingRebates.aspx?action=devicepromo&amp;device=60c0ca0d-b68d-4edd-b667-0d4320b60ede');">Web-only discount</a></td><td class="summaryprice">-$79.99</td></tr>
```

How to Append "you save" below the table and adding the two costs $200+$79.99) in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0;
$(".summaryprice").each(function(){
  sum += getSum(this.html()); // I'm not sure this or $(this) try both
});

function getSum(ammountString){
  var t = ammountString.split('-$');     
  return  parseFloat(t[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var prices = $(".summaryPrice").map(function() {
    return parseFloat($(this).text().replace("-$", ""));
}).get();
for(var sum = 0, i = prices.length; i; sum += prices[--i]);
$("#theTable").after("<p>You save " + sum + "</p>");
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/EkA6p/)

Comment: Hi,Thank you. Its putting 'NaN' in the sum every time and appending.<script>
$(function(){
var prices = $(".summaryprice").map(function() {
    return parseFloat($(this).text().replace("-$", ""));
}).get();
for(var sum = 0, i = prices.length; i; sum += prices[--i]);
$('.summarytotal').before("<p>You save " + sum + "</p>");
});
</script>
I coded like this..

Comment: @sailu - how are you executing it?